# Prove existence of solution for $dX_t = (dX_1(t),dX_2(t))$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Prove existence of strong solution for $dX_t = (dX_1(t),dX_2(t))$

Let

> $\displaystyle dX_t = (dX_1(t),dX_2(t)) = \begin{cases} dX_1(t) = X_2(t)dt + \alpha dB_1(t) \\ dX_2(t) = -X_1(t)dt + \beta dB_2(t) \end{cases}$

Where $(B_1(t), B_2(t))$ is 2-dimensional Brownian motion and $\alpha, \beta$ are constants.

or in matrix notation

> $\displaystyle \bigg [\begin{matrix}  dX_1(t) \\ dX_2(t)  \end{matrix} \bigg ] = \bigg [ \begin{matrix} 0 && 1 \\ -1 && 0\end{matrix}  \bigg ] \bigg[ \begin{matrix} X_1(t) \\ X_2(t)\end{matrix} \bigg]dt + \bigg[ \begin{matrix} \alpha && 0 \\ 0 && \beta \end{matrix} \bigg]\bigg[ \begin{matrix} dB_1(t) \\ dB_2(t) \end{matrix} \bigg]$

According to Oksendal's book, Theorem 5.2.1

> > Let $T>0$ and
> > $$
> > \begin{array}{l}
> > b :[0,T]\times\Bbb R^n \to {\mathbb{R}^n};\\
> > \sigma :[0,T]\times\Bbb R^n\to {\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}};
> > \end{array}
> > $$
> > be measurable functions for which there exist constants $C$ and $D$ such that
> > $$
> > \begin{array}{l}
> > |b(t,x)|+|\sigma (t,x)|\le C(1+|x|);\\
> > |b(t,x)-b(t,y)|+|\sigma(t,x)-\sigma(t,y)|\le D|x-y|;
> > \end{array}
> > $$
> > Let $Z$ be a random variable that is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B_s$, $s ≥ 0$, and with finite second moment:
> > $$
> > E[|Z|^2]<\infty
> > $$
> > Then the stochastic differential equation/initial value problem
> > $$
> > \begin{array}{l}
> > {\rm{d}}{X_t} =b(t,X_t)\mathrm dt+\sigma(t,X_t)\mathrm dB_t,\quad \text{for } t \in [0,T];\\
> > X_0 = Z;
> > \end{array}
> > $$
> > has a Pr-almost surely unique $t$-continuous solution $(t,ω)\mapsto X_t(ω)$ such that $X$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal F_t^Z$ generated by $Z$ and $B_s$, $s\leq t$, and
> > $$
> > E\left[\int_0^T|X_t|^2\,\mathrm dt\right]<\infty.
> > $$

How do I apply this theorem to the above case where there are two differing Brownian motions and matrices involved.

Would $b(t,x) = b(t, (x_1,x_2)) = (x_2, -x_1)$ and $\sigma(t,x) = \sigma(t, (x_1,x_2))  = (\alpha, \beta) $ ?

So I need something like :

$|b(t,x_1, x_2)|+|\sigma (t,x_1,x_2)|\le C(1+|(x_1, x_2)|)$

$\lvert b(t, (x_1,x_2)) - b(t, (y_1,y_2)) \rvert + \lvert \sigma(t, (x_1,x_2)) - \sigma(t, (y_1,y_2))  \rvert \le D \lvert (x_1,x_2) - (y_1,y_2) \rvert $

But the above doesn't quite make sense.

For instance, what is $\lvert (x_1,x_2) \rvert$ supposed to be?

Comment: I just quickly read you question so I may be wrong, however it looks like you have confused yourself with dimenions where there really shouldnt be any confusion. when you say "what is $|(x_1,x_2|)$ supposed to be" your asking what the Euclidian norm of a two dimensional vector is?

Comment: @DanielAdams the Euclidean norm is what I should be using? I Know what that is, so I also take the Euclidean norm for $b, \sigma$ as well in the first condition.

Comment: For $\sigma$ it is the matrix 2-norm I believe. But just read that theorem carefully understanding all the notation and what each object is and its dimension, you should understand it then.

Comment: @DanielAdams I think partially what threw me off is having 2-dimensional Brownian motion. If it were the same Brownian motion, namely a 1-dimensional Brownian motion would it be any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you have not prescribed an initial condition for your SDE. Anyway :

Apply the theorem with

$$b(t,x)=b(x)=(x_2,-x_1),~~~~~~\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}.$$

The Brownian motion in the book mentioned is $B_t=(B_t^1,\ldots,B_t^m)$ where $B_i$ are 1 dimensional Brownian motions, i.e $B$ is an $m$ dimensional Brownian motion, in your case $m=2$.

The first condition to be satisfied is a linear growth condition which usually provides existence of a solution, and the second condition is a Lipschitz in space condition usually providing the uniqueness of the solution (see proof in the book you cited).

These two conditions are easy to check, I think your getting confused not seeing that $|(x_1,x_2)|=|x|$...